# SELENIUM find_element_by_xpath returns 'function' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to create Instagram auto liker bot, The browser fires up and enters the webpage specified and later I am getting the following error
*'function' object has no attribute 'clear'*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=en")
        time.sleep(2)
        user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath
        ("//input[@name='username']")
        user_name_elem.clear()
        user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)
        passworword_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath
        ("//input[@name='password']")
        passworword_elem.clear()
        passworword_elem.send_keys(self.password)
        passworword_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)


ig = InstagramBot("username", "password")
ig.login()
```

Comment: did you type function argumetns in the new line or this was just formatting error?

Comment: did you share the the console error with us?

Comment: I did a line break because the line was too long.

Comment: you should put \ at the end to make a line break

Comment: @akshaypatil user_name_elem.clear()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'clear'

Comment: @amguruprasath, do provide complete traceback all the time. It should include the line number of the error.That will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned in the comment that you broke

```
user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
```

into two lines. That is the problem.
when you did the following

```
user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath
("//input[@name='username']")
```

These two lines got executed separately. So, user_name_elem has become alias for `find_element_by_xpath`
Instead do this to line break

```
user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath \
    ("//input[@name='username']")
```

Comment: how do I break the line properly

Comment: you put a \ at the end of the line

Comment: https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/python-statements/ this might be helpful?

Comment: is this answer helped you

Comment: @akshaypatil, I ran the code, and it worked. You can run the code and then let me know if you are facing any problem